# Python:Unable to extract only specific folders from a tar

Tags: python, tar, attributeerror

I am trying to extract specific folders which I am interested in from big tar file.

```py
import  tarfile
import os

list_dir = []
models = ["usb","test"]
with tarfile.open("build_today.tar.gz") as tar:
for tarinfo in tar.getmembers():
    if tarinfo.name.startswith(os.path.join("build_today","pips")):
        for model in models:
            if tarinfo.name.startswith(os.path.join("build_today","pips",model,"")):
                list_dir.append(tarinfo.name)
    elif tarinfo.name.startswith(os.path.join("build_today","objects")):
        for model in models:
            if tarinfo.name.startswith(os.path.join("build_today","objects",model,"")):
                list_dir.append(tarinfo.name)
    else:
        list_dir.append(tarinfo.name)
print list_dir
tar.extractall(members=list_dir)
```

I am able to get print 'list_dir', Where i can see the content that i am expecting. But it failes while extracting.

**It fails with Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tar.py", line 18, in <module>
tar.extractall(members=list_dir)
File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.10/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2067, in extractall
if tarinfo.isdir():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isdir'
```

Please help!

Comment: please format your code to comply with PEP-8, and use line numbers in the listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a first analysis, seems that the problem is here:

```py
list_dir.append(tarinfo.name)
```

Here you are appending the file name as a string. Instead, you need the "file object" that have the`.isdir()` builtin method